# Decoding output from command line in python

Tags: python, command-line

I'm facing a problem related to decoding the output from command prompt using python.

The script line:

```
command_output = subprocess.run(["netsh", "wlan", "show", "profiles"], capture_output = True).stdout.decode()
```

The error I get:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x94 in position 811: invalid start byte
```

I was expecting to get the list of wifi profiles in string format, I also tried to use latin-1 rather then utf-8 and I didn't get any errors, but this time the output was empty.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best solution, but a good start. It shows the output with umlauts on my Windows PC.

```
import subprocess
command_output = subprocess.run(["netsh", "wlan", "show", "profiles"], capture_output = True, encoding='cp850')
command_output = str(command_output).replace(r'\n', '\n')
print(command_output)
```